# How to convert text to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, formatting

I have a varchar(18) which looks something along the lines of - 000000000000055000. Where this would equal 55.00 where the last digit is always a 0 and the rest of the number is padded with zero.

Other examples would be -

000000000000001260 - 1.26

000000000000039400 - 39.40

How would I convert it from what I have to what I require? Many Thanks

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2012+, I would suggest **try_convert()** rather than just **convert()**.  Try_Convert() will not generate an error, but it will return a null for bogus data.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('000000000000001260')
,('000000000000039400')

Select SomeCol
      ,AsValue  = convert(decimal(18,2),somecol)/1000
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol             AsValue
000000000000001260  1.2600000
000000000000039400  39.4000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If I wanted it to only show 2 decimal places though - how would I go about doing that ...so 1.26 and 39.40 in these examples?

Comment: Something like this seems to work -  convert(decimal(18,2),
  convert(decimal(18,2),BaseValue)/1000
    )

Comment: @ikilledbill  You nailed it.  You did as I would have suggested

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sql?!

btw, the varchar to decimal is implicit converted on t-sql.
try this on a sql query and you can see what i mean.

see this also:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine

```
DECLARE @ValueToConvert VARCHAR(18) = '00000000005320'
DECLARE @ValueConverted Decimal(18,2) = 0

DECLARE @Padding Int = 2
DECLARE @temp1 VARCHAR(18) = SUBSTRING ( @ValueToConvert ,0 ,  CHARINDEX('0', @ValueToConvert,LEN(@ValueToConvert)) - @Padding )
DECLARE @temp2 VARCHAR(18) = SUBSTRING ( @ValueToConvert ,  CHARINDEX('0', @ValueToConvert,LEN(@ValueToConvert)) - @Padding, CHARINDEX('0', @ValueToConvert,LEN(@ValueToConvert)))

set @ValueConverted = (concat(@temp1,'.',@temp2))

SELECT @ValueConverted
```